# How to set up ODBC 10.1b for Progress DB

Tags: odbc, installation, openedge, progress-db

I'm trying to set up an ODBC client driver for Progress 10.1b.  I was able to install the client software that is required, but there is apparently also an ODBC.reg script file that needs to be run to correctly set up the registry in order for me to use the ODBC drivers.

Can anyone point me to where I would find this script?  Or tell me the set of registry entries that would have to be made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a standard part of the install process.

Are [these](http://progress.atgnow.com/esprogress/resultDisplay.do?gotoLink=34198&docType=1000&contextId=36258%3A34198.34279&clusterName=CombinedCluster&contentId=e0fd17e9-a745-4b52-ba42-34f96cd10b4d&responseId=61e197040ff9ab04%3A1b1fbf4%3A121f268d141%3A-12eb&groupId=1&answerGroup=17&score=668&page=https%3A%2F%2Fprogress.atgnow.com%2Fesprogress%2Fdocs%2FProgress%2Fesupport.progress.com%2FEDocHTML%2FOpenEdge%2F10.1B%2Fgsins%2Fgsins-07-1.html&result=28&excerpt=The+installation+also+automatically+adds+entries+when+you+install+an+ODBC+driver.&resultType=5000#Goto34198) the steps that you followed to get the client installed?

If, as you say, the client was properly installed you just need to setup the DSN.  The following should work (stolen and lightly edited from the Progress Knowledge Center):

Start up the ODBC Data Source Administrator(found in Control Panel within the Administrative Tools folder)

Example:

```
1. Select the System DSN tab
2. Select the Add button to the right
3. Select the MERANT 32-BIT Progress SQL-92 driver for your version of Progress.
4. Select Finish
```

That brings up the configuration screen for a new DSN.

Fill-in the following information:

```
1.   Data Source Name..... (whatever you choose)
2.   Description.......(optional and whatever you think is appropriate)
3.   Host Name......(the server where the database is located)
4.   Port Number.... (the port your database broker was started with...if multiple
      brokers..the SQL broker port)
5.   Database Name....(database name you wish to connect to)
6.   User ID...(the user you logged in with or if security is turned on..a user
      that can connect to the database)
7.   Leave all other tab settings at the defaults for the initial configuration.
8.   Select the Apply button.
9.   Select the Test Connect button.
10.  Screen requesting a password pops up. (enter one only if the database
       normally requires a user name and password from the 4GL side to enter the database)
```