# progress ODBC port number 10.2a

Tags: sql, odbc, port, openedge, progress-db

Setting up an ODBC driver through ODBC Data Source Administrator for progress/openedge 10.2a on 64 bit windows 7, (but I'm actually using the 32 bit ODBC Data Source Administrator) I keep getting

Warning:
[DataDirect][ODBC Progress OpenEdge Wire Protocol driver]Connection refused. Verify Host Name and Port Number.[DataDirect][ODBC Progress OpenEdge Wire Protocol driver] Unexpected Network Error. ErrNum = 10038

I've checked my host and it's correct, but I have no idea on the port number, I've checked [connectionstrings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/progress) and it says 2055, a couple other forums online give 20931 as I guess a default port number to use, but both of those aren't working for me.  I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748159/how-to-set-up-odbc-10-1b-for-progress-db), but it doesn't really go into specifics, neither does any documentation other than "put in your port number."

So, how do I find out my port number, or is just a one size fits all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Port numbers are stored in /etc/services for unix, and C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\services for windows.

Each line looks like:

servicename   12345/tcp

so all you need to do is find the servicename in question, get it's corresponding port #, and plug that into your ODBC driver spec.

Comment: Thanks, I'll add that I found out we start our proserve broker manually and that I could pass the port in there, but it's limited by the license to the local machine.  If you happen to know of a work around to that I'd be happy to know, the database we're trying to connect to is on a different server.

Comment: You aren't making sense.  If there is a server on another machine a local proserve isn't relevant.  The ODBC config needs the IP address and port# for the remote db that you are interested in.  Nothing on your local box has anything to do with that.  If the local services file happens to have the service name in it then it might accidentally map to the right port# -- but there is no guarantee of that.  The only way to be certain is to check it on the server.

Comment: When you say "limited by the license" what do you mean?  What sort of license do you have?  And is that the client machine license or the server?

Comment: @Tom Some licenses are localhost only, and can't be accessed from a remote machine.

Comment: I get that.  The "personal" db.  But he seems to be describing a situation where there are multiple systems at least one of which sounds like a server rather than a personal system and if he is testing with the restricted license (as he seems to be) then the conclusions drawn about making connections may not be warranted.

Answer (score 1):

There is no default port number.  The port name or number is specified in the database startup on the server.  You should contact the administrator of the database and find out what it is.  If there is no DBA search the log file (dbname.lg) for "-S".